# How To Fill The Offset With Material?

Tags: mesh

I making a mesh of lattice (soft and hard parts) the soft parts are the squares and the hard one I have to fill the offset with. I tried to select each adjacent vertices, but nothing work out.

Also, I have a problem how to assign different young Modulus for this mesh, do anyone has an idea?

In reality it looks like that picture:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello. This is not really clear to me. Do you want a mesh that deforms from the left part of the image to the right part? Or do you simply want to reproduce the left part?

Comment: I updated the picture, I do want to do a lattice and then I am going to use fixed constraint and apply a force to see the strain rate. Let me know if that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use array for such surfaces

[image]

Then I will apply Arrays and close boundary using Bridge Edge loops

[image]

Next I need a subdivided plane, and I'll add cloth simulation on it. I need to add two vertexes at corners in a new vertex group to use as a pin group, so that the surface will appear like it held by corners.

[image]

Finally, I will add a surface deform on the lattice, so that it will follow plane deformations.

[image]

Comment: That is indeed helpful! I want to ask how you did the first mesh is not clear for me (figure1)

Comment: Start with plane, extrude, scale to center, extrude, move up, extrude, scale back. Then remove top and bottom polygons

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, I still so new to blender, is there a example I can follow?

Comment: https://gifyu.com/image/Can8

Comment: Thanks so much you made my day! Do you have any idea how to assign different young Modulus to a mesh in Blender, in that example, I have to do that?